# Log4net Error Application Run on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

'Unrecognized element 'log4net'.'
Kindly please help me..
I will be very thankful to you

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very poor right now. It is not answerable unless you should provide more information about your case..

Comment: Put some code please where you have this error, and we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add log4net to your config file but forget to declare it in your custom config section?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `<log4net>` section to a `web.config` file you also need to declare that element in the `<configSections>` element at the top.

See the ".config files" section on this web page: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html